# Is it possible to copy whole userland into other machine in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, configuration

AFAIK, FreeBSD has strict separation between base system and userland. IMO, theoretically, it seems possible to transfer whole userland to other machine by simple copying. If the base systems are equal (version)

Can I actually copy the userland by simple copying? If it's possible what directories should I copy? If it is not, what's the major reason which prevent copying userland configurations?

**Update**

The term *userland* seems to be wrong in the text. My intention was **stuffs of full OS except base system**, and I don't know correct wording for this.

Comment: “Userland” means “everything but the kernel”. Evidently you're using it to mean something else, but what? Software that isn't part of the base system?

Comment: @Gilles That was the my original intention. Maybe I don't know correct term for that. What's the correct term for that? *Add-on*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple copying is insufficient because `cp` doesn't preserve uids/gids, flags, hard/symlinks etc. But you can easily copy userland with `tar`.

If you have mean packages/ports when say "userland" you have to try `pkg create -a` command that creates in current dir bundles for all the software installed from ports/packages. That bundles can be easily copied to the other machine(s) and installed there with `pkg add *`. Sure, you have to copy all configuration files manually.